# Connect differents apps react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm currently doing a project for a company that wants a webiste where users and clients can hadle their products (sold by the company).
The point is that products are really different and also clients have only some categories of products.
The website is composed by a main app and some micro-services that are divided form the main app and are different projects themselfs

Is it possibile to connect those apps with react-router (like a SPA application)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Sure you can split your app using `react-router`, but at the same time you'll be downloading both applications, because you're working on a SPA (Single Page Application).

Luckily stage3 to the rescue. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import 
Dynamic imports allow you to split the code (babel can take care of that) and resolve the page using a promise. Please take a look at https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable which is a nice way to integrate this technique into React.